# OfType() vs. Cast() with class filter

Tags: c#, linq

I know that the basic difference between `Cast()` and `OfType()` in LINQ is that `Cast()` might not be able to cast all objects and throws an exception in that case.

But what about this:

```
var p in PersonCollection.GetData().Where(p => p is Student).Cast<Student>()
```

and

```
var p in PersonCollection.GetData().OfType<Student>()
```

Is there any difference between these methods? Or is `OfType()` basically just a shorthand version of the first?

Comment: @CodeCaster: i changed the duplicate

Comment: @Tim no problem, even a better one.

Comment: The result is the same but `OfType` is more concise/readable and also a little bit more efficient [[source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d25cf953c577dcd6,references)]